# Customized CMS functionality for the end-user. Like a control panel

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, drupal-7, content-management-system

I have been asked so often for **custom CMS functionality** where the end-user wants to manage his content by his hands using a control panel or something.

A college professor wanted to manage his online magazine issues and papers, a manager wanted to upload and manage news and photos about his firm. and so on

In this case the client doesn't have any technical knowledge about Wordpress or Joomla or Drupal and he needs a customized solution that fits his needs.

**The content strucure is different in each case, and sometimes end-users can be involved to register/log-in to the site and manage their own submitted data. so each registered user manages his own content.**

I managed that requirement differently each time and i wonder if i can have a better solution in the future.

In other words, I want for a solution where i can **tailor** the CMS for the customer according to his requirements.

I heard that Drupal is a good choice since it is more a content management framework and less a CMS, i wonder also about Wordpress and Joomla since they're both obviously easier to learn and work with. do i have to build a customized control panel for each client every time?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K2 for joomla supports front-end editing and each user edits his own content.